# How to make bottom sheet dialog able reach height till top of screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-bottomsheetdialog

I recently created a bottom sheet in my app, whose height is enough to fit the screen. But when I run the app and open the bottom sheet dialog, it doesn't open up till the top (I mean up-to it's maximum height, due to which some of it's bottom contents remain hidden). Even if I try to drag it up till the top of screen, it stops after reaching a particular height.

Can anyone please suggest a programmatic way to let the user drag the bottom sheet to its full height?

Please help!

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: Could you edit the post by adding your code, please?